# Asking Allah for forgiveness for certain acts committed out of ignorance or forgetfulness

Tags: sex, sin, forgiveness

I am a new Muslim, and it is hard to sometimes remember what is permitted and what is not. I recently had relations with my wife and realized that some of what we did may (or may not) be permissible in Islam. How does a Muslim ask forgiveness? Is it free form prayer? Dua? Tajahud? How, when and why?

I want to be a good Muslim and need to know that I have not ruined my situation.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. A very basic question - how is dua performed? During salah? At the end?

Comment: one can perform du'a' at any time, in and out of prayers.

Answer (score 1):

Although you did not specify exactly what sin you are asking about, the Prophet ﷺ informed us that three exemptions alleviate the punishment of a sin:

- Error or lack of knowledge
- Forgetfulness
- Being forced or deprived of a willful action.

This was narrated in a hadith narrated by [Abu Dhar al-Ghifari](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abu_Dhar_al-Ghifari) and another narrated by ['Abdullah ibn 'Abbas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abd_Allah_ibn_Abbas) (quoted below):

> عَنِ ابْنِ عَبَّاسٍ، عَنِ النَّبِيِّ ـ صلى الله عليه وسلم ـ قَالَ: إِنَّ اللَّهَ وَضَعَ عَنْ أُمَّتِي الْخَطَأَ وَالنِّسْيَانَ وَمَا اسْتُكْرِهُوا عَلَيْهِ
>
> It was narrated from Ibn 'Abbas that the Prophet (ﷺ) said: "Allah has forgiven my nation for mistakes and forgetfulness, and what they are forced to do."
>
> <sub>— [Sunan Ibn Majah, Book 10, Hadith 2123](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/1321240)</sub>

First, you need to do is ask about whether an act is permissible, and the degree (permissibility could be obligatory, preferred or neutral; whereas non-permissibility could be not encouraged, not allowed except under certain pretexts, or not allowed under any circumstances, etc. — this is not a comprehensive list). For certain topics that require an in-depth knowledge, you will not be able to get a definitive answer on an online forum; a *fatwa* (decree) will be required from scholars.

Second, if an act is committed that falls under any of the above exemptions, still ask for Allah's forgiveness. Allah ﷻ tells us in the Qur'an [Surat Al-Ahzab 33:5](https://quran.com/33/5/) that "And there is no blame upon you for that in which you have erred but only for what your hearts intended." As Noah ﷺ advised his people, one should always attribute to Allah due grandeur:

> فَقُلْتُ اسْتَغْفِرُوا رَبَّكُمْ إِنَّهُ كَانَ غَفَّارًا يُرْسِلِ السَّمَاءَ عَلَيْكُم مِّدْرَارًا وَيُمْدِدْكُم بِأَمْوَالٍ وَبَنِينَ وَيَجْعَل لَّكُمْ جَنَّاتٍ وَيَجْعَل لَّكُمْ أَنْهَارًا مَّا لَكُمْ لَا تَرْجُونَ لِلَّهِ وَقَارًا
>
> And said, 'Ask forgiveness of your Lord. Indeed, He is ever a Perpetual Forgiver. He will send [rain from] the sky upon you in [continuing] showers. And give you increase in wealth and children and provide for you gardens and provide for you rivers. What is [the matter] with you that you do not attribute to Allah [due] grandeur?'
>
> <sub>— [Surat Nuh 71:10-13](https://quran.com/71/10-13/)</sub>

Third, one can ask for forgiveness during prayer, by offering additional prayers to Allah ﷻ, by *du'a'* (supplication), by giving *sadaqa* (charitable donations), etc. Any form of a good deed is potentially an option:

> عَنْ أَبِي ذَرٍّ جُنْدَبِ بْنِ جُنَادَةَ، وَأَبِي عَبْدِ الرَّحْمَنِ مُعَاذِ بْنِ جَبَلٍ رَضِيَ اللَّهُ عَنْهُمَا، عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه و سلم قَالَ: اتَّقِ اللَّهَ حَيْثُمَا كُنْت، وَأَتْبِعْ السَّيِّئَةَ الْحَسَنَةَ تَمْحُهَا، وَخَالِقْ النَّاسَ بِخُلُقٍ حَسَنٍ
>
> On the authority of Abu Dharr Jundub ibn Junadah, and Abu Abdur-Rahman Muadh bin Jabal (may Allah be pleased with him), that the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him) said: "Have *taqwa* (fear) of Allah wherever you may be, and **follow up a bad deed with a good deed which will wipe it out**, and behave well towards the people.
>
> <sub>— [40 Hadith Nawawi 18](https://www.sunnah.com/nawawi40/18)</sub>

Last, Allah ﷻ commands us in the Qur'an not to despair of his mercy, which is greater than one can imagine:

> قُلْ يَا عِبَادِيَ الَّذِينَ أَسْرَفُوا عَلَىٰ أَنفُسِهِمْ لَا تَقْنَطُوا مِن رَّحْمَةِ اللَّهِ ۚ إِنَّ اللَّهَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ جَمِيعًا ۚ إِنَّهُ هُوَ الْغَفُورُ الرَّحِيمُ
>
> Say, "O My servants who have transgressed against themselves [by sinning], do not despair of the mercy of Allah. Indeed, Allah forgives all sins. Indeed, it is He who is the Forgiving, the Merciful."
>
> <sub>— [Surat Az-Zumar 39:53](https://quran.com/39/53)</sub>

Allah ﷻ does not forgive association of others with Him but may forgive any sin other than that. All we need to do is ask for His forgiveness:

> إِنَّ اللَّهَ لَا يَغْفِرُ أَن يُشْرَكَ بِهِ وَيَغْفِرُ مَا دُونَ ذَٰلِكَ لِمَن يَشَاءُ ۚ وَمَن يُشْرِكْ بِاللَّهِ فَقَدِ افْتَرَىٰ إِثْمًا عَظِيمًا
>
> Indeed, Allah does not forgive association with Him, but He forgives what is less than that for whom He wills. And he who associates others with Allah has certainly fabricated a tremendous sin.
>
> <sub>— [Surat An-Nisa 4:48](https://quran.com/4/48/)</sub>